# Why is Chlormephos highly toxic despite requiring metabolic activation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, proteins, enzymes, organophosphorus-compounds

According to the book "The Chemistry of Organophosphorus Pesticides", the insecticide Chlormephos (S-(chloromethyl) O,O-diethyl phosphorodithioate) has an oral LD50 in rats of 7 mg/kg. For reference, the oral LD50 in rats for diisopropyl fluorophosphate is around 5 mg/kg. Why is chlormephos only slightly less toxic than DFP despite the fact that it would presumably require metabolic activation before being able to inhibit acetylcholinesterase due to the presence of a P=S bond? I would presume that the presence of a chloromethyl instead of methyl group contributes to the toxicity of chlormephos in some way, as [the methyl analog is several times less toxic than chlormephos](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/18682#section=Toxicity), but how? And why is chlormephos only slightly less toxic than DFP despite the fact that chlormephos would require metabolic activation before being able to inhibit AChE, while DFP would not?

Comment: If metabolic activation creates a really nasty toxin when an otherwise harmless compound is ingested, the initial harmlessness doesn't matter.

Comment: @matt_black according to that same book, parathion has an ld50 in rats of 6.4 mg/kg. So I suppose a better question would be "Why is the toxicity of chlormephos on par with that of parathion?"